# Write Range to Table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a range to table. Most of the time I'd just write an array to the table but this time I need to preserve formulas across my macro. I copy pasted my code from writing an array and tweaked it but across all my variations, I can't make it work.

```
Function WriteRangeToTable(InputRange As Range, TableName As String, SheetName As String)
    Dim MyTable As ListObject: Set MyTable = Worksheets(SheetName).ListObjects(TableName)
    If MyTable.DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        Set MyTable.InsertRowRange.Resize(InputRange.Rows.Count, InputRange.Columns.Count) = InputRange
    Else
        Set MyTable.DataBodyRange.Resize(InputRange.Rows.Count, InputRange.Columns.Count) = InputRange
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Why are you using `Set`? After removing the `Set`, note that your current approach won't maintain formulas. You could copy / pastespecial for that, among other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's great that you have this small routine to do the copying plus using listobjects - thumb up!

But in this case you have to use `PasteSpecial` together with  `xlPasteFormulas`